# Securely clearing bytearray after crypto

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

I have a bytearray, which contains a passphrase, which is being fed to scrypt as KDF (PyNaCl).

I don't want the passphrase hanging around in memory, but just doing

```
passphrase = b""
```

seems to me insufficient, since it's a rebinding of passphrase to a new object, and we wait for garbage collection to ensure the bytes are gone from the memory of the python process.

So if I'm not being uselessly paranoid, what's the most efficient way of expunging the bytes from the bytearray?

I've currently got

```
passphrase[:] = b"\x00" * len(passphrase)
```

but is there a more pythonic way?